# jQuery UI Sortable and Dialogue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to drag jQuery UI Sortable list items between two lists, one of which is in a jQuery UI Dialogue and one which is not?

I am trying to create a dialogue where users can drag form fields out of a dialogue into a form which is on the page, but I can't drag the items out of the dialogue border.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

It seems that the dragging and droppings is actually working, but you can't see the item once you go beyond the dialogue. This isn't really ideal. (see [redsquare's demo](http://jsbin.com/afomu))

**Another Edit**

The main div that gets created for the dialogue has `overflow:hidden` on it. If I disable this in Firebug the dragging works properly, so I guess I could somehow override this, but I suspect that will cause me more problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Demo [here](http://jsbin.com/afomu).

Does this replicate your issue? I am able to drag between the two however you do lose the helper when you drag out of or into the dialogue. I think it may need to adjust the z-indexing when you move out or in of the dialog but it is still functional...just!

I'll try to sort this when I have a bit more time later.

UPDATE: tweaking the z-index helps (well helps dragging from the list to the dialogue - the first time!)...will make it better later! see [here](http://jsbin.com/ugola)

**NEW UPDATE New Demo here, I had to make use of the helper to ensure the z-index stayed correct. Works now [here](http://jsbin.com/ogima)**

Comment: Thanks - I didn't actually realise that the dragging was still working, I had assumed that because I couldn't see the item whilst dragging,  it wasn't working at all. But I would like to be able to see the dragged item at all times ideally.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with sorting elements between dialogs, so thanks to redsquare for the code. Have been able to simplify the code a bit further, to this self-contained bit (no extra markup required):

```
this.sortables = $( sortSelector ).sortable( {
    connectWith: sortSelector,
    zIndex : 99999,
    helper: function() {
        var helper = $( '.sortHelper li' );
        if ( !helper.length ) {
            helper = $('<ul><li></li></ul>')
                .addClass( 'sortHelper' )
                .appendTo( 'body' )
                .find( 'li' )
                .css( { 'z-index': 9999 } );
        }

        return helper;
    },
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.helper.text( ui.item.text() );
    }
});
```

Demo at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJhnn/).