# JQueryUI Sortables in Between Multiple Dialogs Connection/Floating Issues

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

**Issue:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Drath/Y9k3P/

I've been having this issue connecting two jQueryUI sortable lists in between two dialogs. The issue comes down to floating. If you move the sortable around it's own dialog, it works perfectly. If you try to move it to the other dialog, it will fail to register as the element that "accepts" the sortable has no height, because all of it's elements are floated.

**What I've tried:**

Tried using `display:inline-block` instead of float. This does work, but makes drag/drop movement really glitchy/sporadic and does weird things to the layout.

Tried using all the different clearfix/float methods (to force a container size). These work as well but drag/drop movement is again glitchy/sporadic.

Tried setting a specific container height with same effect of as clearfix methods.

Tried a million different combinations of the sortable options.

I'm open to suggestions and possible alternative solutions to emulate this effect/functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with your code I have finally made it work.

I think the key point here is the `float: left;` statement in `#sortable1, #sortable2` selector.

I have also converted your divs to ul and li combinations. I haven't tried the solution with divs.

Here is my jsJiddle solution: http://jsfiddle.net/AramCH3K/5xKuh/3/

I haven't work much on the glitch when dragging items which shows a dot in front of the text. It is related with cloning the list item but I don't know how to style the cloned item. There must be a way to add `list-style-type: none;` style to it.

**Edit:**

I have updated my code by using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5552393/362935) in order to overcome the dragging glitch.

Here is my updated jsFiddle solution: http://jsfiddle.net/AramCH3K/U6LVa/

**Final Edit:**

In my [updated solution](http://jsfiddle.net/AramCH3K/U6LVa/1/) I have used cloning and I think it has provided a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Luckily, I still needed the fix after all this time. I notice in your examples, after you drag out all of the elements, you are not able to place them back in either dialog. I was able to solve this by adding:

`min-height: 32px;
width: 100%;`

To the <ul> elements.